# High speed parameters for transistor

Tags: transistors, high-speed, totem-pole

How to choose a Bipolar Junction Transistor (BJT) for a switching frequency of 400KHz.

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Question is not at all for specific product.What parameters i should see in Datasheet to choose.

Comment: Capitalizing Random words Makes it Very Hard To read.

Comment: If you want pulse-in pulse-out, then examine the stored-charge during saturation. The 2N697 and 2N2369 were designed (if I recall correctly) as quick-to-leave-saturation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I would get a transistor to switch at 400 kHz, then I would look for a transistor with a bandwidth of at least 400 kHz, I'd probably look for a transistor with 1 MHz for some margin because the real world is messier than in theory.

But what I'd also look for would be the minimum \$h_{fe}\$, because that will greatly affect the efficiency of the BJT, or what kind of things you can use the BJT for. Also the maximum amperage (through Ic). But since your question is screaming of much effort put into the question, I don't know what other kind of parameters you should be looking for, rather than 400 kHz bandwidth.

If you are going to make something that needs a lot of amp's, say more than 0.5 A, then I'd strongly advice you to use a MOSFET instead of a BJT.

Comment: "If I would get a transistor to switch at 400 kHz, then I would look for a transistor with a bandwidth of at least 400 kHz". Exactly which parameter in Datasheet i should look for in Switching Characteristics.

Comment: Yes, just click [here](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/P2N2222A-D.PDF) and search for "Bandwidth". It's the famous 2N2222. This one got 300 MHz. But I'd lay more weight on other parameters if I know _what_ the BJT transistor should _do_.

Comment: I got it. i require it for Totem pole,and I dont need current beyond 50mA, as it will go in Pulse Transformer, which will drive MOSFET.